# Get normalized form data from BoundField in django template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a `ModelForm` with some `IntegerField`s and `DecimalField`s, and I need to render them on server using current locale format for view, and using regular format for JS interop.

Currently I'm using `form.currency.value|default:1|stringformat:"d"` for integers and `form.rate.value|default:0|stringformat:"f"` for decimals.

But since that's form, when there's bound data in form, `form.rate.value` is string, and `stringformat` returns empty string.

Is it possible to access normalized data from template? If yes - how? If no - how should I handle both cases? Handling this in view for each and every field seems like an overkill, but handling types in template seems no better.

Best way I can think of is to register custom filter, handle types there, return string with number literal.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to extract the data from the bound field? Why don't you just display the field? Or, separately send whatever data populated the field in the first place?

Comment: I want to use that data to initialize frontend with it, namely Vue component, and with Vue I want to pass that directly in an template as an form component attribute. When rendering initial form data with numbers they end up being encoded with spaces, or with comma as a decimal separator. So far best option I found is to just use unlocalize.